# Erro ao acessar índices de array dentro de uma expressão LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

Estou fazendo uma query para procurar todas as meteorologias com determinada data, mas ao executar ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```
var metereologias = from b in db.Metereologias.Where(b => b.data_de_leitura.Equals(tmp[i]))
                                   select new MetereologiaDTO()
                                   {
                                       metereologiaId = b.metereologiaId,
                                       data_de_leitura = b.data_de_leitura,
                                       hora_de_leitura = b.hora_de_leitura,
                                       temperatura = b.temp,
                                       vento = b.vento,
                                       pressão = b.pressao,
                                       NO = b.NO,
                                       NO2 = b.NO2,
                                       CO2 = b.CO2,
                                       Local = b.Local.Nome
                                   };
                List<MetereologiaDTO> tmpResult = new List<MetereologiaDTO>(metereologias);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para corrigir o problema use uma variável temporária para armazenar o valor no índice `i` da matriz `tmp`:

```
var tempValue = tmp[i];
var metereologias = db.Metereologias.Where(b => b.data_de_leitura.Equals(tempValue))
                                    .Select(new MetereologiaDTO
                                    {
                                       metereologiaId = b.metereologiaId,
                                       data_de_leitura = b.data_de_leitura,
                                       hora_de_leitura = b.hora_de_leitura,
                                       temperatura = b.temp,
                                       vento = b.vento,
                                       pressão = b.pressao,
                                       NO = b.NO,
                                       NO2 = b.NO2,
                                       CO2 = b.CO2,
                                       Local = b.Local.Nome
                                    }).ToList();

var result = new List<MetereologiaDTO>(metereologias);
```

Se você usar um índice de matriz `tmp[i]` dentro de uma expression tree, ele tentará converter isso em uma expressão também, ocasionando em erro.

### ATUALIZADO

Atualizei o código adotando um padrão - fazendo todos os comandos através da interface fluente, mas da forma que você escreveu o seu código funcionará igual.